# JAX-RS @POST Syntax

Tags: java, post, jax-rs

I have not used `@POST` before and am not sure about the syntax and how to test.  Here's what I have now:

```
@GET
@Path("classroomAssignmentId/{classroomAssignmentId}/classroomId/{classroomId}/assignmentName/{assignmentName}/assignmentDesc/{assignmentDesc}/assignmentDueDt/{assignmentDueDt}/assignmentDocument/{assignmentDocument}/assignmentStatusId/{assignmentStatusId}/updatedBy/{updatedBy}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)


public ClassroomAssignment getCandidatesAsJson( @PathParam("classroomAssignmentId") int classroomAssignmentId
                        ,@PathParam("classroomId") int classroomId
                        ,@PathParam("assignmentName") String assignmentName
                        ,@PathParam("assignmentDesc") String assignmentDesc
                        ,@PathParam("assignmentDueDt") String assignmentDueDt
                        ,@PathParam("assignmentDocument") String assignmentDocument
                        ,@PathParam("assignmentStatusId") int assignmentStatusId
                        ,@PathParam("assignmentTypeId") int assignmentTypeId
                        ,@PathParam("updatedBy") String updatedBy)
```

I want to change the `@GET` to `@POST`.  Need help with syntax and how to test the WS call through a browser.

Comment: That's [tag:jax-rs], not JPA. What do you hope to accomplish by changing GET to POST?

Comment: Don't want to expose all the parameters in the URL.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here.

First, merely wanting to express your parameters differently is insufficient for changing the semantics of your call. A POST is fundamentally different from a GET, and both semantics are very clearly defined in REST. You shouldn't switch just for convenience sake.

But second, if you find the theory pedantic and just care about how to practically get this done, you will use something like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/classroom-assignment)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ClassroomAssignment getCandidatesAsJson(CandidateObject myObject) {
...
}
```

Then you will need your JAX-RS provider (RESTEasy, Spring MVC, Restlet, etc.) to perform automatic deserialization of JSON (typically with Jackson) to the `CandidateObject` POJO, which will have getters and setters mapping to the fields in your original query string of your GET.

At least that's the default serialization, which will be sufficient and easiest.

You will also have a `ClassroomAssignment` POJO, and your JSON serializer (again typically Jackson) will convert that POJO to JSON.

But ultimately, if a GET worked before, you should probably keep things as GET. Just rethink your design and how the GET call is made.

Comment: Makes sense execpt for this part: <BR>Then you will need your JAX-RS provider (RESTEasy, Spring MVC, Restlet, etc.) to perform automatic deserialization of JSON to the CandidateObject POJO, which will have getters and setters mapping to the fields in your original query string of your GET.  <BR>If my CandidateObject is ClassroomAssignment, do I still need to do what you say?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "CandidateObject is ClassroomAssignment." The request and the response are both JSON. But you want to use Java representations of these JSON values. This means the JSON request needs to be converted to `CandidateObject` and that `ClassroomAssignment` needs to be converted to a JSON response.

Comment: My question is will this work:
@POST
@Path("/classroomAssignment")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 
public ClassroomAssignment getCandidatesAsJson( ClassroomAssignment thisClassAssignment)